# How to make customize switch button with image ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I want to know how to customize a switch in Flutter to look like this :

[image: switch button]

I don't want to know how to make the shape etc. But how to put an image in the track.
I know there are :

```
inactiveThumbImage
activeThumbImage
```

But it is not what I want.
Maybe something like `activeTrackImage`, but I didn't find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_switch) which adds the functionality to add an image to a switch widget..

```
AdvancedSwitch(
          controller: _controller,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
          inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
          activeImage: const AssetImage('assets/images/on.png'),
          inactiveImage: const AssetImage('assets/images/off.png'),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
          width: 100.0,
          height: 30.0,
          enabled: true,
          disabledOpacity: 0.5,
        )
```

which gives the following result

***OFF***

[image: Off]

***ON***

[image: On]